# Does jobRepository have to use the same transaction manager as the JdbcBatchItemWriter?

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch

I am developing a Spring Batch enterprise application. The objective of the application is to write records to a table in a legacy database from the company I work for. That database is really big boy that stores business and customer information in huge number of schemas and tables with hundreds of millions of records, there are also hundreds of applications that connect to it: ERPs, CRMS, internal applications, .com.

Because of that, I cannot create the job metadata tables needed by the jobRepository as I cannot create new tables in that legacy database. But at the same time I need to be able to monitor the jobs so I want jobRepository to point to another datasource.

Should I just create another transaction manager and use it in the jobRepository? I am using tasklet steps with chunk tasks and JdbcBatchItemWriter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, they use the same transaction manager. In your situation you need a JTA transaction manager because you write data (batch-medatada and business-data) to two different database.
Read [this comment](https://blog.codecentric.de/en/2012/03/transactions-in-spring-batch-part-1-the-basics/#comment-161192) and few next; it is well explained.

Comment: Thanks @bellabax, the problem with jta transaction manager is that it works with xa transactions, we are working with Tomcat 6 which does not support xa datasources like J2EE app servers do. So we would need to use a third party jta xa solution like atomikos, etc. The problem with that is that they require xa compatible drivers and we are only allowed to use the approved jdbc drivers. Also I dont know if there exist xa drivers for the as400 i5 series data base. Any idea?

Comment: I'm sorry, but I can't help about that. I faced XA tx problem once times (~6 yrs) ago, but company didn't accept our solution so we dumped (and only from MSSQL and PostgreSQL).