# Spring batch transaction manager for two databases

Tags: spring-batch, spring-jdbc, spring-batch-admin

I am reading from a database and writing to another database via Spring Batch. Do I need two transaction managers? I am reading 'n' rows from the first database, processing them then writing 'm' rows into the second database. I am using jdbc but not JPA or Hibernate.

Comment: keywords to search: XA, two-phase commit, distributed transaction. In brief, make sure you have XA-aware driver for both DB, and have a proper transaction manager (get from the container normally. I remember there is some non-container txn manager impl but I haven't tried)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

XA is necessary only when target datasource (where data are written, I mean) is different from datasource holds SB metadata tables. If target database is the same one contains metadata tables, no XA is required.
In addiction, [`AbstractCursorItemReader`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/trunk/apidocs/org/springframework/batch/item/database/AbstractCursorItemReader.html)-based use a separated connection for reading.

> By default the cursor will be opened using a separate connection. The
>   ResultSet for the cursor is held open regardless of commits or roll
>   backs in a surrounding transaction. Clients of this reader are
>   responsible for buffering the items in the case that they need to be
>   re-presented on a rollback. This buffering is handled by the step
>   implementations provided and is only a concern for anyone writing
>   their own step implementations.

(Look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18795882/does-jobrepository-have-to-use-the-same-transaction-manager-as-the-jdbcbatchitem/18801333#18801333), too)